# Power BI - How to manage relationship between 2 tables for 1 to many rows

Tags: powerbi, relationship, dax, powerpivot

I have 2 tables

Table A

```
Category Type   Start time  Severity Status
Issue           July 2019   High    Closed
Config          July 2019   Low     Closed
Config          July 2019   High    Open
Bug             Sep 2020    Medium  Open
Training        Aug 2020    High    Open
Config          Sep 2020    Low     Closed 
Config          Sep 2020    Medium  Closed
Config          Oct 2020    Low     Open
Config          Oct 2020    Low     Closed
Config          Oct 2020    Medium  Open
```

Table B

```
Category Type   Start time  value
Issue           July 2019   1
Config          July 2019   2
Bug             Sep 2020    1
Training        Aug 2020    3
Config          Sep 2020    2 
Config          Oct 2020    3
```

I have created a Column Chart with Table B having month on X-axis and Category with count on Y-axis and Table A is simple table chart.

Now when I select Category "Config" in July 2019 which has value "2" on column chart, it shows all the 7 config records in other table instead of only 2 of that July 2019 month which I have selected.

What should I do that it shows only those 2 July 2019 records instead of all the same category type records in other table ? There is no 1 to 2 row active relationship is possible in Power Bi
Currently I am having 1-1 relationship between category type in both tables.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new column in both table by concatenating Category type and Month column in both table and creating a join on that new column.

[image]
Image 1 
Sheet 1 : `Concat = Concat = Sheet1[Category Type] &"-"& Sheet1[Start Time].[Month] &"-"& Sheet1[Start Time].[Year]`

Sheet 2 : `Concat = 'Sheet2'[Category Type] &"-"& 'Sheet2'[Start Time].[Month] &"-"& 'Sheet2'[Start Time].[Year]`

[image]
Image 2 - Displaying data in both table without any selection or filter

[image]
Image 3 - Displaying data after selecting row for Category type as 'config' and start time as 'July 2019'

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Himanshu, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of relationship between table in model based on new Concat column and Data display after selecting row from table 2. Let me know if you are trying to do something else.

Comment: Wow thats amazing Himanshu it worked. I was concatinating just on both column but not on month and year. It worked perfectly as I was expecting. Thanks again for your help.